# bedmas process with intel 8086 assembly lanuage

Tags: intel, x86-16, emu8086

I am trying to solve the equation: 7 * (4 + 10) + (15 / 5) for example in assembly language. I assume the BEDMAS principal still applies, but the code I run is not giving me the correct numerical value? I am not sure where I am going wrong. When we invoke `DIV`, does it not automatically divide the value from the `AX` register?

```
MOV BX,10
ADD BX,4
MOV AX,15
MOV BL,5
DIV BL
ADD AX,BX
MOV BX, 7
MUL BX
HLT
```

Comment: The CPU has no idea of the formula you're trying to compute. It's up to you to generate the right sequence of operations for your computation.

Comment: would you be able to point me in the right direction of where  am going wrong?

I set the first bracket equation to the BX register, added the value of 5 to the BL register so I could divide the AX register, then I add them at the end and multiply BX by 7? or am I missing something?

Comment: `div bl` does AL = AX/BL, and AH = AX%BL, like it says in the instruction-set reference manual (http://felixcloutier.com/x86/DIV.html).  But `mov bl, 5` overwrites the low byte of BX.  You might want to use CL for your divisor since you still have the `4+10` result in BX.  Or do the division first.  Use a debugger to single-step through your code.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> MOV BX,10
> ADD BX,4
> MOV AX,15
> MOV BL,5          <<<< This overwrite the sum 10 + 4 in BX
> DIV BL
> ADD AX,BX         <<<< Luckily remainder was zero
> MOV BX, 7
> MUL BX            <<<< Needlessly clobbers DX
> ```

Apart from some other imperfections, this calculation **does not even follow normal algebraic rules**.
You've calculated 7 * **(** (4 + 10) + (15 / 5) **)** when the task asked for **(** 7 * (4 + 10) **)** + (15 / 5)

- On [8086](/questions/tagged/8086) both division and multiplication use the accumulator, so inevitably you'll have to move the result from whichever of these you choose to do first in an extra register.
- The byte sized division yields a quotient in `AL` but also a remainder in `AH`. This task asks you to continu with the quotient disregarding the remainder. Your code does not explicitely zero `AH` and that's not good enough for a generalized solution! Luckily 15 / 5 gave a remainder = 0.

Solution with division before multiplication:

```
mov ax, 15
mov bl, 5     ;Divider in BL
div bl        ;AX/BL -> AL=3 (remainder in AH=0)
mov bl, al    ;Move to an extra register
mov al, 4
add al, 10    ;AL=14
mov ah, 7
mul ah        ;AL*AH -> AX=98
add al, bl
```

Solution with multiplication before division:

```
mov al, 4
add al, 10    ;AL=14
mov ah, 7
mul ah        ;AL*AH -> AX=98
mov bh, al    ;Move to an extra register
mov ax, 15
mov bl, 5     ;Divider in BL
div bl        ;AX/BL -> AL=3 (remainder in AH=0)
add al, bh
```

Both solutions produce the same result (101) and use just 2 registers (`AX` and `BX`).